# How to convert Multiplication sign into Asterisk sign in python?

Tags: python, math, character-encoding, special-characters, identifier

I have a math solver python program but it can't read "×" sign, so It can not solve the equation. Is there any way to convert "×" into "*"?

**Python shell:**

```
>>> 3 × 5
`SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
>>> 3 * 5
15
>>>
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZKi2.png)

**Update:**
I tried this too, but did not work.

```
 if (parser.getPayload().lower()[:6]=="solve:"):
                    if ("×" in parser.getPayload().lower()):
                        str.replace("×","*")
                        parser.sendGroupMessage(parser.getTargetID(), str(ast.literal_eval(parser.getPayload()[7:])))
```

Comment: [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)?

Comment: what solver ? maybe it can get equation as string, or it use different sign then "×" .

Comment: What kind of equations are you dealing with? Are they always going to be digits, operator, digits?

Comment: @furas yeah. it gets equation as string.

Comment: @idjaw equations are random. Like 10 + 5 / 2 × 6

Comment: @bharat I'm sorry, the screenshot you showed is confusing me. Is this an application you wrote? How exactly are you interfacing with it? What kind of control do you have on the code?

Comment: Perhaps you can change equations by using string replace function and then perform operations.

Comment: @idjaw it is an instant messenger and I have created a program to solve mathematics equations provided by a bot.

Comment: @idjaw Unicode number of that character is U+00D7. I don't know what to do now.

Comment: @bharat I'm not sure exactly how the code looks like on your end, but I think there is something you can try. I can post an answer. If it isn't it, I'll delete.

Comment: if it gets equation as string then use `str.replace` "3 × 5".replaca("×", "*")

Comment: or "3 × 5".replace("\u00D7", "*")

Comment: I'm starting to think my solution is not applicable here. Is the idea here to convert to a string representation of a mathematical formula to send to the bot the interacts with the app?

Comment: @idjaw yeah
`if (parser.getPayload().lower()[:6]=="solve:"):
                        parser.sendGroupMessage(parser.getTargetID(), str(ast.literal_eval(parser.getPayload()[7:])))`

Comment: Could you give me a link to the full program, I might try to debug it.

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp http://www.filedropper.com/mathsolver

Comment: Your code is bugging out everywhere for me, I can't test it properly - what version of Python is this?

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp 3.5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go over your code line by line.

```
if (parser.getPayload().lower()[:6]=="solve:"):
```

Fine I guess, don't know your protocol but makes sense this way.

```
                    if ("×" in parser.getPayload().lower()):
```

Converting to lower case should not be needed. If it were, caching that might be useful. I also wonder whether you need that check, or whether you might as well do the replacement unconditionally, since that makes the code easier and should't be much of a performance problem. It might even help performance since you avoid scanning for the first `×` twice.

```
                        str.replace("×","*")
```

[`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) is a method of the class `str`, not a function in some module called `str`. You need to call the `replace` method on your payload. So either use something like `parser.setPayload(parser.getPayload().replace("×","*"))` or store the payload in a local variable which you can modify.

```
                        parser.sendGroupMessage(parser.getTargetID(), str(ast.literal_eval(parser.getPayload()[7:])))
```

Are you sure you only want to do this in the case there is a `×` in the input? Anyway, read [the docs for `ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval): it will not evaluate operators. So this is not what you need. If you need to evaluate operators, you may call `eval`, but if you do, you **must** sanitize your input first to ensure it doesn't do anything evil.

I'd do something like this:

```
sanitizeRegexp = re.compile(r"\A[0-9+\-*/ ]*\Z") # only allow these
payload = parser.getPayload()
if payload.lower()[:6] == "solve:":
    payload = payload[7:] # strip command
    payload = payload.replace("×", "*")
    if sanitizeRegexp.match(payload):
        result = str(eval(payload))
    else:
        result = "Invalid input: " + payload
    parser.sendGroupMessage(parser.getTargetID(), result)
```